# What is the best way to tell users to scroll down in browsers?

Tags: web, html, scrolling, browser, user-attention

**what is the best way to tell users to scroll down in browsers?**

Tests showed, that users do not scroll to the original message (which they need to answer questions):

[image]

Comment: Scroll bars are the canonical answer here. Additionally, you can put an end marker at the end, as a hint, so that the users learn that the absence of the marker (with the presence of the scroll bar) means there's more to see. An ellipsis might also be useful, although you could argue that the convention of using an ellipsis in software to indicate something more follows is the opposite of the original intention.

Comment: https://www.nngroup.com/videos/fold-manifesto/ directly answers some of this.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from arranging these two fields side by side instead of stacked as shown?

Comment: I have same general question as OP. Scroll bars cannot be shown manually, in FireFox for example so this is not the answer. How do I indicate that a user should scroll when it's not obvious?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. First of all, you should not end a page at blank spaces. You should end them at the top portion of the next page's first section.
   [image]
2. Use scroll icons such as this:
   [image]
   to inform the user about the available action.

Comment: Thanks :-) The ending of page is pretty random, due to different screen and browser window sizes. So this problem affects not all users.

Comment: I will check, if it is possible to scroll to an anchor, which brings the answer part to the visible screen section.

Comment: Actually, the ending is not random. You can write code for the % of the viewport which the div should occupy.

Comment: Ok, I will ask the developer, what is the best way to show the beginning of the "below the fold" div, without leaving content away/let the page jump.

Comment: Cool. But I suppose t is vice versa from a development pov. You should set the first section to be like 80% or 90% of the viewport. the next container would automatically come to the above-shown position.    You could check this link if required: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622027/percentage-height-html-5-css/1622097#1622097

Comment: Use a graphical element ( a thick line will do) which runs down the page and across the fold.

Comment: @PhillipW Yes.. That is a great contemporary design element that applies here quite well.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ways to tell users to scroll, but the key is to prevent people from thinking it's the end of the page in the first place. Prevent a *false bottom*. Show a hint of the next segment, especially since you have a send action within the visible space. A lot of people will click here without checking the rest of the page, even if you do show a hint of the next segment. You may want to evaluate if you can change the hierarchy of the page.

If your design doesn't allow you to redo the layout so it's more obvious you can scroll, you can add an [animated 'scroll' icon](https://cdn.codemyui.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Pure-CSS-Site-Scroll-Micro-Animation.gif) or [pulsing arrow that points downward](https://cdn.codemyui.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Dripping-Down-Arrow.gif). These are more band aids than that they actually fix the issue though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailled answer and the example link. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Either place the drop-down icon to let users that there is something below the page or just add continue reading box after some text of the article.