# Avoid "illusion of completeness" on list of items

Tags: lists, content

I'm stuck with a client request that says his users don't really know they can scroll to see more content. See below some images to understand better (the first image is the problem, the second is the solution I propose). Will this be enough?

[image: The problem]

[image: My suggestion]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this a web app or a mobile app?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it's not particularly for mobile device but web (including desktop). I see in the link you sent that they advise to add some gradient on the edge, which is one of the solution I had, in addition to display the scroll bar.

Comment: Duplicate for desktop https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/115110/115107

Comment: What is the solution? The double scroll bar or the almost unnoticeable light shadow at the bottom? Both aren't very good ideas. But can you make the question less like a review question and share your doubts, test results etc.?

Comment: Could also list the number of promotions in the heading

Comment: Thank you for your input all, I think the number of promotions is a good idea.